# How to set the background image for achartengine line chart in android?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using achartengine to dispaly  the line chart in my application.I need to add the bg image for the chart , but when I set the bg image in xml , its not working. Have anyone tried this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did u try? posting some source code will help.

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't support Background Image but you can set Color [like This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711586/android-how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-graph-using-achartengine)

Answer (score 14):

Firstly, you need to add chart into your activity, and set preferred image as background in activity layout. (Take a look at XYChartBuilder in AChartEngineneDemo to see how to do that)

Secondly, set transparent background for chart and chart margin:

```
mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent_background));
```

Finally, create your own transparent background since the Color.TRANSPARENT doesn't work for chart margin:

```
<color name="transparent_background">#00FF0000</color>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: you set background image in your activity layout and set transparent color for your chart. Just follow my instruction.

Answer (score 7):

You just replace that code of line with this one:

```
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));
```

Comment: Don't understand why the nicer Color.TRANSPARENT doesn't work for setMarginsColor, but this did it... thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This can be possible to set the background of line chart. it was a trick that works for me.

```
// RelativeLayout layout_ChartView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_View);  
private GraphicalView mChartView;  
if(mChartView==null){
mChartView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg));
layout_ChartView.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,300));  
mChartView = ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView(this,mDataset,mRenderer, 0.2f);  
}
else{    
  mChartView.repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you set your margincolor?
Like this?

```
mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.RED);
```

This will give a whole view of your graph background to red color

Comment: That is the ticket! Thanks :) setMarginsColor() missed that while looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
```

And the Layout background where show the chart set your background image. 
Done.

Answer (score 1):

**For removing:**

```
mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{0,0,0,0});
```

And it will remove the margin :) its simple

**For setting color:**

```
mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set transparent background color, you can try:

```
renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
```

It just be work for me!